# Highcharts series drawn over contextButton

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like my chart area to be extended on the top so I've added a negative margin to the chart.  However, this causes series at times to be drawn over the contextButtons and can make them impossible to click.  I'd like to just increase the z-index or do something that makes them appear above the series without having to make my own buttons that live outside the chart.  Does anyone have a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a code example showing what you're doing now?

Comment: The only relevant code is in the chart configuration I do `chart.marginTop = -15`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tu67e1ce/1/

```
chart: {
    marginTop: -25,
    events: {
        load: function() {
            this.exportSVGElements[0].toFront();
            this.exportSVGElements[1].toFront();
        }
    }
},
```

So method `toFront()` will bring items on top of the SVG container. `this.exportSVGElements[0]/[1]` are button/symbol. Of course both of them are inner object of the Highcharts core.

Comment: This is incredible, thanks!  Since I actually have multiple of those buttons I just had to loop over them and call toFront()